# How to use Laravel's auth middleware password-reset feature without scaffolding

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, middleware, scaffolding

I removed Laravel's scaffolding with the command `php artisan fresh`. I read the Auth middleware documentation, but it didn't talk about a specific feature, the password-reset. It only explains its use with the scaffolding, but not if I removed it. There is chapter "Manuel authentication" for common authentication methods, such as "determining if a user is authenticated", but nothing about password-reset.

Other point, does this middleware need specific rows in the DB tables I created with migrations ? Especially "users" and "password_resets" tables configured in the `app\config\auth.php` file.

This problem may seem simple, but I didn't find any clue in the documentation.

Thanks for help !